# How to get the child's parent in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am working on a silverlight probject. I want to set the property of parent in a child class. However, I do not know how to get the parent instance. So How can I get the child's parent in silverlight.

Comment: Please read the rules... you have not given any code and your description is simply not adequate for us to help you. What type of class is it? - Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VisualTreeHelper class to get the child's parent.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a C# class that you have created and you want to find the 'parent', i.e. a class that has an instance of the child as a property or member variable.

There is nothing in the language that will do this for you. If you want a bi-directional relationship you will have to create this manually. i.e. supply the Child class an instance of its Parent on construction.